# Identify book about girl who creates warmth with musical instrument

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm looking for a book but I forgot the title. Its a fictional young adult book where a girl is kidnapped by a man. His people are freezing to death. The girl can create warmth and heat by playing a flute-like instrument.

Comment: When did you read it? Was it new or old then?

Answer (score 7):

I was just looking for this book too!

This is [Singer in the Snow](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/440696.Singer_in_the_Snow) by Louise Marley.

> On the ice planet of Nevya, **people rely on Cantors and Cantrixes,
>   men and women with the ability to channel psi energy through music,
>   creating heat and light.** Mreen is possibly the most talented Cantrix
>   on Nevyaabut she is unable to make a sound. She is accompanied to her
>   first posting by a younger Singer, Emle, who must come to terms with
>   her own flawed Gift. When the two young women find out about Gwin, a
>   young girl whose abusive stepfather wants to exploit her psi-Gift
>   talents, they find that in reaching out to her, they can also help
>   themselves.

**Enjoy!**

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is [*Rhapsody* by Elizabeth Hayden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Haydon#The_Rhapsody_Trilogy)?